# Wordpress migration and upgrade

Tags: php, wordpress, centos

I have recently updated my WordPress server, from CentOS 5 to CentOS 6.5 and migrated my WordPress installation. Everything looks fine, expect at the top of every page it shows:

```
", "", $excerpt); $excerpt = str_replace("
", "", $excerpt); if (strlen($excerpt > 0)) echo strip_tags($excerpt); else echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "description", true);?>" />
```

My WordPress version is 3.8.1.

Why is this showing up?

Comment: What is the complete code to the piece you've given in your answer. What error do you get in debug mode

Comment: I think this are the lines at wp-trackback.php: `// These three are stripslashed here so they can be properly escaped after mb_convert_encoding().
$title     = isset($_POST['title'])     ? wp_unslash($_POST['title'])      : '';
$excerpt   = isset($_POST['excerpt'])   ? wp_unslash($_POST['excerpt'])    : '';
$blog_name = isset($_POST['blog_name']) ? wp_unslash($_POST['blog_name'])  : ''; if ($charset)
        $charset = str_replace( array(',', ' '), '', strtoupper( trim($charset) ) );
else
        $charset = 'ASCII, UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, JIS, EUC-JP, SJIS';`

Comment: `if ( false !== strpos($charset, 'UTF-7') )
        die;
// For international trackbacks.
if ( function_exists('mb_convert_encoding') ) {
        $title     = mb_convert_encoding($title, get_option('blog_charset'), $charset);
        $excerpt   = mb_convert_encoding($excerpt, get_option('blog_charset'), $charset);
        $blog_name = mb_convert_encoding($blog_name, get_option('blog_charset'), $charset);
}
// Now that mb_convert_encoding() has been given a swing, we need to escape these three.
$title     = wp_slash($title);
$excerpt   = wp_slash($excerpt);
$blog_name = wp_slash($blog_name);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the `short_open_tag` in php.ini. Enabling it, works!

Comment: WordPress by itself is compatible with `short_open_tag Off`, which is the default setting, so your problem has to be in some plugin or custom code that you wrote, not in `wp-trackback.php`.  Since it is possible that a future version of PHP will remove `short_open_tag`, you should instead find any occurrences of plain `<?` and change them to `<?php` in any code that you wrote or customizations you applied. (Note that `<?=` is not counted as a short open tag as of PHP 5.4, so you can leave that.)